# Reading characters from command prompt and using them for path-name in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, 16-bit, dosbox

my program has purpose: read symbols from command line and use them as full path-name going to another directory.
This program works if instead of inputting symbols from command line i define buffer as `P:\test\`, so the problem is in the reading characters.
However, i tried to print out my buffer by using: ah 02h int 21h (single character output) and it outputted it correctly.

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data   
    dir db 255 dup (0)
 
.code
start:
    mov dx, @data
    mov ds, dx
    
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, es:[80h]
    mov si, 0082h ;reading from command prompt 0082h because first one is space
    xor bx, bx

l1:
    mov al, es:[si+bx]          ;filling buffer
    mov ds:[dir+bx], al
    inc bx
    loop l1

    mov dx, offset dir           ;going to directory
    mov ah, 3Bh
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4ch
    mov al, 0
    int 21h

end start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the command line resides always a `0Dh`. So the value in `es:[80h]` (count of the characters in the command line) is one too big. Also, the end of the path must be nullified for [`Int 21h/AH=3Bh`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2777.htm) ("ASCIZ" means: ASCII characters plus zero).

This one should work:

```
.model small
.stack 1000h                    ; Don't skimp on stack.

.data
    dir db 255 dup (0)

.code
start:

    mov dx, @data
    mov ds, dx

    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, es:[80h]
    dec cl                      ; Without the last character (0Dh)
    mov si, 0082h               ; reading from command prompt 0082h because first one is space
    xor bx, bx

    l1:
    mov al, es:[si+bx]          ; filling buffer
    mov ds:[dir+bx], al
    inc bx
    loop l1

    mov byte ptr [dir+bx], 0    ; Terminator

    mov dx, offset dir          ; going to directory
    mov ah, 3Bh
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h               ; Exit with 0
    int 21h

end start
```

Do you consider, that you cannot change the drive letter with `Int 21h/AH=3Bh`?

Comment: So the problem was that my path-name consisted "carriage return" on the end? Secondly, " mov byte ptr [dir+bx], 0 " i thought that all my buffer "dir" is filled with 0 except command line input? So this line is not essiantial? Yes, I know that i cannot change drive letter with this interrupt.

Comment: @Pijus: Ad 1: Yes. Ad 2: Yes. To be on the safe side.

Comment: by the way is it necessary to use fill with (0) or is it possible to use ('$')? Not only in this case, for ex in getting current directory.

Comment: @Pijus: In this case, the terminator is (0). ('$') is the terminator for `Int 21h/AH=09h`. Sometimes you don't need a terminator but  a certain count of bytes to process. Look always at Ralf Brown's documentation (http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/ix/21/ or http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your help and useful links!